# Running two independent events simultaneously in android

Tags: android, animation, media-player

I am new to android and stuck up at some point in the app i am currently developing. In my `onCreate` method I have two independent tasks : First is playing sounds in an array using `for` loop and Second is an `onClickListener` to an image that makes it animate on click. The sound starts perfectly as soon as I start the app, My problem is when I click the image, it animates as required but it stops the sound. How can I play sound and animation independent of each other? Any help/idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

This sounds very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AsyncTask in android it will update the ui too in method updateProgress in android

Comment: Thanks...Async Task does help in running my music in bg while still doing the animation...

Answer (score 0):

You can use service for playing music.Services are designed to continually running in the background.

```
public class MyService extends Service {



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   MediaPlayer  player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setVolume(1f, 1f);
    player.start();
```